# How to place javascript banner using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to put a javascript ad banner using javascript. Here is the code

```
 <script>
 document.write("<script src="http://adsite.com"></script>");
 </script>
```

But its not working. How can i solve it. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
  document.write('<script src="http://adsite.com"></script>');
```

Check your quotes

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your quotes with `\"`:

```
document.write("<script src=\"http://adsite.com\"></script>");
```